# Faceting in Solr when index contains millions of documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I'm working on a project that uses a solr index with a few million documents and we've recently hit a memory problem. Faceting has become unusable on a couple of our fields - solr runs out of heap memroy - because of the number of documents containing those fields.

What options do we have besides increasing the memory? We see memory increases as a temporary solution because the number of documents goes up by a few 100k documents per day.

I'm looking at the minute into solrcloud but I'm not sure this is the right solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The `facet.method` is a good hint, which one are you using?

Comment: the default one, which ever it is. I do a search for facet.method to see which is the right one :)

Comment: Each request allocates memory temporarily for faceting. How many concurrent requests do you have?

Comment: when I encountered the problem it was only my request because I was using the dev sever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **FacetFields:** Allow for facet counts based on distinct values in a field. There are `two methods` for FacetFields, one that performs well with `few distinct values` in a field, and the other for when a field contains `many distinct values` (generally, thousands and up – you should test what works best for you).
>
> The first method, `facet.method=enum`, works by issuing a FacetQuery for every unique value in the field. As mentioned, this is an excellent method when the number of distinct values in a field is small. It requires excessive memory though, and breaks down when the number of distinct values gets large. When using this method, be careful to ensure that your `FilterCache` is large enough to contain at least one filter for every distinct value you plan on faceting on.
>
> The second method uses the Lucene `FieldCache` (future version of Solr will actually use a different non-inverted structure – the UnInvertedField). This method is actually slower and more memory intensive for fields with a low number of unique values, but if you have a lot of uniques, this is the way to go. This method uses the `FieldCache` to look up the values for the given field for each document, and every time a document with a given value is found, the value has its count incremented.

Please check the allotted memory for each cache and if you can tweak `FieldCache` to handle the situation. (As you have mentioned, `type3` and `type4` have large number of documents.

Source for the above information is [Scaling Lucene and Solr](http://lucidworks.com/blog/scaling-lucene-and-solr/). I found one more article which talks about solr faceting [You are faceting it wrong](https://sbdevel.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/you-are-faceting-itwrong/).

Comment: That's great info! Had no idea there were two methods for faceting. I'll look more into it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Before solrcould you can think of solr multiple core.

On a single instance, Solr has something called a SolrCore that is essentially a single index. If you want multiple indexes, you create multiple SolrCores.

With SolrCloud, a single index can span multiple Solr instances.

This means that a single index can be made up of multiple SolrCore's on different machines.

These SolrCores that make up one logical index a collection.

A collection is a essentially a single index that spans many SolrCore's, both for index scaling as well as redundancy.

If you wanted to move your 2 SolrCore Solr setup to SolrCloud, you would have 2 collections, each made up of multiple individual SolrCores.

SolrCloud adds the distributed capabilities in Solr. 
With this enable you can have highly available, fault tolerant cluster of Solr servers.

Use SolrCloud when you want high scale, fault tolerant, distributed indexing and search capabilities.

You can get more info about SolrCloud here

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud

Comment: How would I use multiple cores though? How do I decide which docs go in which cores?

And more importantly, how do I search on two nodes?

Comment: core can be used a category. For example you have set of books belongs to category technical, agriculture and novel. You can create three core of these categories and add the books to the respective category. with this if you in which category to search you can fire a request to the respective core.

Comment: here is link which tells you how to manage cores...https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API

Comment: do you have any segregation within the documents?

Comment: not really! That's kind of the problem. I have 4 types of documents. However, type 3&4 I doubt that will ever get to more than a million documents. type 1 usually gets the most documents and type 2 close after

Comment: so with this you can have 3 cores one for type1 and type2 and third one is common for both type 3&4...